# Aligning text at top in tabular (tikzposter block)

Tags: tables, alignment, tikzposter

I have a table with text and a picture in a tikzposter block.

```
\documentclass[20pt, a0paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usetheme{Simple}

\begin{document}
\begin{columns}

\begin{columns}
\column{0.5}
\block{Geographical Area}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.5\linewidth} p{0.5\linewidth}}
    hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! 
    &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,]{PIC.pdf}
\end{tabular}
}

\end{columns}
\end{document}
```

In a zoomed picture it yields a table like this:
[image]

I'm trying to align the text at the top in the left cell so it looks like this:
[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `valign=t` option (needs the `adjustbox` package with the `export` option) in order to top align text and image in a table. In the following example, I also adjusted the widths of the two table columns in order to get rid of the overfull box warning.

[image]

```
\documentclass[20pt, a0paper, landscape]{tikzposter}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usetheme{Simple}

\begin{document}

\begin{columns}
\column{0.5}
\block{Geographical Area}{
\begin{tabular}[t]{*{2}{p{\dimexpr 0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}}
    hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! hello world! 
    &
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,valign=t]{example-image}
\end{tabular}
}

\end{columns}
\end{document}
```